# Does multi dimension array matter when passing it to a function?

Tags: c++, arrays

So i have a function and a MD array

```
int arrayMD[2][2] = { 0,3,6,8 };


void display(int *ptr) {
     cout << *(ptr + 1);
 }

display(*arrayMD, 2, 2); // Invoke
```

When I pass the it to the function it will point to a 1-D Array

so the `*ptr` would point to `{0,3}` (CMIIW)

When I call a function / invoke

I pass a dereferenced pointer which is : An Address

`cout << *arrayMD == Address to the first one which is {0,3}`

so the function should be `*ptr = Address from dereferenced Argument passed`

So when i try to double bracket on the array: `ptr[0][1]` it doesn't work because it has become 1 dimensional array which consist of `{0,3}` but when i type `ptr[3]` it printed out `8`. I know how it stored in the memory but is there no limit? so i could just use one dimensional array and print out the value. Then what's the point of 2D array?

I have just started learning C++ so please CMIIW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's put it this way first:

```
void display(int (*ptr)[2]) { // Takes a pointer to an array of 2 ints
    std::cout << **(ptr); // Display [0][0]
    std::cout << *(*(ptr)+1); // Display [0][1]
    std::cout << **(ptr+1); // Display [1][0]
    std::cout << *(*(ptr+1)+1); // Display [1][1]
}

int main() {
    int arrayMD[2][2] = { 0,3,6,8 };
    display(arrayMD); // Here, we pass the pointer to the first element of arrayMD
}
```

This gives us the following output:

```
0368
```

As you know, when we use the name of an array, it is automatically converts to the pointer to the first element. But when we want a pointer to an array, **we need involvement of parenthesis**:

```
int *p[100]; // is an array of 100 pointers to int
int (*p)[100]; // is a pointer to an array of 100 int
```

And yes, in general, **consider using Standard Library**, in particular the `std::array`.